# Deploying docker image to web app on Linux via Azure Devops fails

Tags: linux, azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to deploy my docker image to a `web app for containers (Linux)` via the release pipeline in `Azure Devops`. I am using the task `Azure Web App for Containers` to accomplish this.

Building and pushing the image to my private container registry in Azure works fine.
But when I'm trying to deploy my newly built and pushed image, I get an **authentication error**.

Azure Devops reports the deployment went fine but when I am looking in the docker logs in the tab `container settings` in Azure I see an authentication error.
If I try to deploy my image directly in the `container settings` it works as expected.

Previously I have my service connection to my Azure subscription and I also added a separate service connection for my Azure Container Registry.
I am not using docker compose and I try to deploy a single image/container.

Azure Devops logs:

```
2019-08-12T13:48:47.3512681Z ##[section]Starting: Azure Web App on Container Deploy: my-service
2019-08-12T13:48:47.3676562Z ==============================================================================
2019-08-12T13:48:47.3676709Z Task         : Azure Web App for Containers
2019-08-12T13:48:47.3676775Z Description  : Deploy containers to Azure App Service
2019-08-12T13:48:47.3676828Z Version      : 1.0.22
2019-08-12T13:48:47.3676870Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-08-12T13:48:47.3676932Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-containers
2019-08-12T13:48:47.3677003Z ==============================================================================
2019-08-12T13:48:47.6472308Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'my-service'
2019-08-12T13:48:48.7565776Z Single-container Deployment to the webapp 'my-service' as only the image detail was sepcified.
2019-08-12T13:48:49.2180101Z Updating App Service Configuration settings. Data: {"appCommandLine":null,"linuxFxVersion":"DOCKER|my-registry.azurecr.io/my-repository:latest"}
2019-08-12T13:48:51.1744261Z Updated App Service Configuration settings.
2019-08-12T13:48:51.1752210Z Restarting App Service: my-service
2019-08-12T13:48:51.6881923Z App Service 'my-service' restarted successfully.
2019-08-12T13:48:54.9987139Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://my-service.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/12431565617733135
2019-08-12T13:48:55.5252693Z App Service Application URL: https://my-service.azurewebsites.net
2019-08-12T13:48:55.5391444Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure Web App on Container Deploy: my-service
```

[image]

Docker logs in Azure:

```
2019-08-12 07:54:11.184 INFO  - Pulling image: my-registry.azurecr.io/my-service:20190812.8
2019-08-12 07:54:11.424 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"manifest for my-registry.azurecr.io/my-service:20190812.8 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown"}

2019-08-12 07:54:11.425 ERROR - Pulling docker image my-registry.azurecr.io/my-service:20190812.8 failed:
2019-08-12 07:54:11.426 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: my-registry.azurecr.io/my-service:20190812.8
2019-08-12 07:54:11.461 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://my-registry.azurecr.io/v2/my-service:/manifests/20190812.8: unauthorized: authentication required"}

2019-08-12 07:54:11.463 ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2019-08-12 07:54:13.482 INFO  - Pulling image: my-registry.azurecr.io/my-service:20190812.8
2019-08-12 07:54:13.588 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"manifest for my-registry.azurecr.io/my-service:20190812.8 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown"}

2019-08-12 07:54:13.593 ERROR - Pulling docker image my-registry.azurecr.io/my-service:20190812.8 failed:
2019-08-12 07:54:13.593 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: my-registry.azurecr.io/my-service:20190812.8
2019-08-12 07:54:13.628 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://my-registry.azurecr.io/v2/my-service:/manifests/20190812.8: unauthorized: authentication required"}

2019-08-12 07:54:13.629 ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2019-08-12 07:54:17.116 INFO  - Pulling image: my-registry.azurecr.io/my-service:20190812.8
2019-08-12 07:54:17.244 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"manifest for my-registry.azurecr.io/my-service:20190812.8 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown"}

2019-08-12 07:54:17.245 ERROR - Pulling docker image my-registry.azurecr.io/my-service:20190812.8 failed:
2019-08-12 07:54:17.246 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: my-registry.azurecr.io/my-service:20190812.8
2019-08-12 07:54:17.281 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://my-registry.azurecr.io/v2/my-service:/manifests/20190812.8: unauthorized: authentication required"}

2019-08-12 07:54:17.283 ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
```

Anyone experienced the same problem?
Do I explicit need to provide the credentials to the registry even though I added a service connection in Azure Devops?

Comment: Do I need to setup a `Service Principal` for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a last resort I got it to magically work by removing my service connection to the subscription in Azure Devops and added it back. (No need to have a separate service connection for your Azure Container Registry)

Highly frustrating!

Comment: Hi @Hypnobrew I tried the same thing but im still receiving the error could you look at my pipeline?